# How can I get the path of the most recently taken image on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, path, camera, uiimage

In apps such as Tweetbot there is a "choose most recent picture" function.  I would like to know what the path is for the most recent image in the camera roll.

I know that when I pick an image from camera roll manually, the code to retrieve said image looks like this:

```
UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

What I do not know is what to put in the info valueForKey for the newest picture.  I googled extensively and found nada.  I know the rules- I am supposed to show what I have tried, but I am at a loss as to what to try, as I am finding zilch in my research and am not familiar with file path related programming.

I read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html) and found nothing of use.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the most recent photo is stored in the UIImage named latestPhoto. Hope this helps!

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
     [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
      {
          if (alAsset)
          {
              ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
              UIImage *latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];
          }
      }];
 }
 failureBlock: ^(NSError *error)
 {
     // an error has occurred
 }];
```